# HD44780 LCD - proper addressing for overseas 16x4 line display

Tags: lcd, character-lcd

I bought a few 16 character by 4 line LCD's from ebay that are HD44780 compatible and today I was testing them.

The LCD advertisement is at: http://www.ebay.ca/itm/LCD-16x4-1604-Character-LCD-Display-Module-LCM-Yellow-Blacklight-5V-Arduino/401053633069

Various sources (including http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/142-16x4-lcd-line-addresses) tell me that:

> For displaying the characters on the 1st line send the command 0x80 
>   For displaying the characters on the 2nd line send the command 0xC0 
>   For displaying the characters on the 3rd line send the command 0x94 
>   For displaying the characters on the 4th line send the command 0xD4

I did use these codes for specifying the beginning of the line. The first two lines of the display are correct but the last two lines are always indented in by 4 spaces (with the last set of characters missing) no matter what I display on the screen.

For example, If I wanted to display "0123456789ABCDEF" on the first or second line, all of it will fit and be displayed. However, if I tried it on the third or fourth line then I would see "    0123456789AB".

Upon examining the LCD module circuit board, the only labels I see are the pin definitions on each side and on the back side, I see a big label "1604A".

I'm tempted to try 0x90 for the 3rd line and 0xD0 for the 4th line, but before I do, is there a way to know regardless of the display I use which addresses represent the start of each line?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked one of my LCD libraries.  I have in there "for a 4x16 line display the offset is 16 or 20".  So, yes, move your offsets.  Use 0x90 and 0xD0.